# A word or phrase for the boring writing style "thing after thing after thing", like a "ledger"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose you want to write a story. Your final writing is like the following:

> This morning Doe got up at 7:45am. Then he brushed his teeth. Then he had
>   breakfast which was prepared by his mom. Then he spent the whole morning
>   reading a novel. He had lunch with his parents at 1:00pm. After lunch, he
>   took a nap for about 20 minutes. Then he went out with his friends and
>   spent a good time in the afternoon. ...

This is not story-telling. This is event-describing. In Chinese, we call this kind of writing a "**ledger**" which suggests **"boring; too many unrelated details; without a proper focus"**.

Note, however, that "ledger" is only used as criticism when the writing's original intent is story-telling.

**What is the English word or phrase to call such writing?**

Comment: *boring* is fine.  *dull*. *prosaic*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the word ***log*** (or ***logbook***):

> **2.1** A regular or systematic record of incidents or observations.
>
> - *‘keep a detailed **log** of your activities’*
>
> <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/log)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

One English idiom you might consider is "one damn thing after another".

The original is variously claimed to be ["Life is one damn thing after another"](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/09/02/life-one/) or ["History is one damn thing after another"](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/09/16/history/), and is variously attributed to Edna St Vincent Millay, Elbert Hubbard, Arnold Toynbee and others.

However, the phrase "one damn thing after another" may be quoted on its own. That phrase has even been used, reduced to its initials ODTAA, as the title of [a novel by John Masefield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODTAA).